# wxpython openfiledialog Set Directory

Tags: python

I would like to know how to change the directory when the openfiledialog is open.I would like to set it to a specific directory.

```
def OnOpen(self,event):
        """Open a file"""
        openFileDialog = wx.FileDialog(self,"Open log file","","","Log files (*.log)|*.log",wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST |wx.FD_CHANGE_DIR)

        if openFileDialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_CANCEL:
            return

        input_stream = wx.FileInputStream(openFileDialog.GetPath())

        if not input_stream.IsOk():
            wx.LogError("Cannot open file '%s'."%openFileDialog.GetPath())
            return
```

I have see function such as setdirectory.I do not know where to apply that parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the default directory of a `FileDialog` *after* it is created, but *before* it is shown:

```
def OnOpen(self,event):
        """Open a file"""
        openFileDialog = wx.FileDialog(self,"Open log file","","","Log files (*.log)|*.log",wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST |wx.FD_CHANGE_DIR)

        openFileDialog.SetDirectory(some_dir)

        if openFileDialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_CANCEL:
            return
        ...
```